# Why my red-black tree implementation benchmark shows linear time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, go, red-black-tree

The implementation basically follows [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Here is how I implemented the benchmark, in this case, it is benchmarking `Put` op:

```
func BenchmarkRBTree(b *testing.B) {
    for size := 0; size < 1000; size += 100 {
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("size-%d", size), func(b *testing.B) {
            tree := NewRBTree(func(a, b interface{}) bool {
                if a.(int) < b.(int) {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            })
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                for n := 0; n < size; n++ {
                    tree.Put(n, n)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkRBTree/size-0-8              2000000000              0.49 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-100-8                200000             11170 ns/op            7984 B/op        298 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-200-8                100000             26450 ns/op           15984 B/op        598 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-300-8                 50000             38838 ns/op           23984 B/op        898 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-400-8                 30000             55460 ns/op           31984 B/op       1198 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-500-8                 20000             62654 ns/op           39984 B/op       1498 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-600-8                 20000             80317 ns/op           47984 B/op       1798 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-700-8                 20000             91308 ns/op           55984 B/op       2098 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-800-8                 10000            106180 ns/op           63984 B/op       2398 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-900-8                 10000            121026 ns/op           71984 B/op       2698 allocs/op
```

A visual line chart of `ns/op`:

[image]

Even I increase the problem size:

```
BenchmarkRBTree/size-0-8              2000000000              0.50 ns/op               0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-10000-8                1000           1622187 ns/op          799989 B/op      29998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-20000-8                 500           3693875 ns/op         1599994 B/op      59998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-30000-8                 300           5693788 ns/op         2399998 B/op      89998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-40000-8                 200           7663705 ns/op         3199998 B/op     119998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-50000-8                 200           9869095 ns/op         3999997 B/op     149998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-60000-8                 100          12133795 ns/op         4799999 B/op     179998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-70000-8                 100          15422763 ns/op         5599999 B/op     209998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-80000-8                 100          16140037 ns/op         6399998 B/op     239998 allocs/op
BenchmarkRBTree/size-90000-8                 100          18161217 ns/op         7199997 B/op     269998 allocs/op
```

Visual chart:

[image]

You can check the code in [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wmQi5u53KE_W), or a lengthy version:

```
type color uint32

const (
    red color = iota
    black
)

type rbnode struct {
    c      color
    left   *rbnode
    right  *rbnode
    parent *rbnode
    k, v   interface{}
}

func (n *rbnode) color() color {
    if n == nil {
        return black
    }
    return n.c
}

func (n *rbnode) grandparent() *rbnode {
    return n.parent.parent
}

func (n *rbnode) uncle() *rbnode {
    if n.parent == n.grandparent().left {
        return n.grandparent().right
    }
    return n.grandparent().left
}

func (n *rbnode) sibling() *rbnode {
    if n == n.parent.left {
        return n.parent.right
    }
    return n.parent.left
}

func (n *rbnode) maximumNode() *rbnode {
    for n.right != nil {
        n = n.right
    }
    return n
}

// RBTree is a red-black tree
type RBTree struct {
    root *rbnode
    len  int
    less Less
}

// Less returns true if a < b
type Less func(a, b interface{}) bool

// NewRBTree creates a red-black tree
func NewRBTree(less Less) *RBTree {
    return &RBTree{less: less}
}

// Len returns the size of the tree
func (t *RBTree) Len() int {
    return t.len
}

// Put stores the value by given key
func (t *RBTree) Put(key, value interface{}) {
    var insertedNode *rbnode

    new := &rbnode{k: key, v: value, c: red}
    if t.root != nil {
        node := t.root
    LOOP:
        for {
            switch {
            case t.less(key, node.k):
                if node.left == nil {
                    node.left = new
                    insertedNode = node.left
                    break LOOP
                }
                node = node.left
            case t.less(node.k, key):
                if node.right == nil {
                    node.right = new
                    insertedNode = node.right
                    break LOOP
                }
                node = node.right
            default: // =
                node.k = key
                node.v = value
                return
            }
        }
        insertedNode.parent = node
    } else {
        t.root = new
        insertedNode = t.root
    }
    t.insertCase1(insertedNode)
    t.len++
}

func (t *RBTree) insertCase1(n *rbnode) {
    if n.parent == nil {
        n.c = black
        return
    }
    t.insertCase2(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) insertCase2(n *rbnode) {
    if n.parent.color() == black {
        return
    }
    t.insertCase3(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) insertCase3(n *rbnode) {
    if n.uncle().color() == red {
        n.parent.c = black
        n.uncle().c = black
        n.grandparent().c = red
        t.insertCase1(n.grandparent())
        return
    }
    t.insertCase4(n)

}
func (t *RBTree) insertCase4(n *rbnode) {
    if n == n.parent.right && n.parent == n.grandparent().left {
        t.rotateLeft(n.parent)
        n = n.left
    } else if n == n.parent.left && n.parent == n.grandparent().right {
        t.rotateRight(n.parent)
        n = n.right
    }
    t.insertCase5(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) insertCase5(n *rbnode) {
    n.parent.c = black
    n.grandparent().c = red
    if n == n.parent.left && n.parent == n.grandparent().left {
        t.rotateRight(n.grandparent())
        return
    } else if n == n.parent.right && n.parent == n.grandparent().right {
        t.rotateLeft(n.grandparent())
    }
}

func (t *RBTree) replace(old, new *rbnode) {
    if old.parent == nil {
        t.root = new
    } else {
        if old == old.parent.left {
            old.parent.left = new
        } else {
            old.parent.right = new
        }
    }
    if new != nil {
        new.parent = old.parent
    }
}

func (t *RBTree) rotateLeft(n *rbnode) {
    right := n.right
    t.replace(n, right)
    n.right = right.left
    if right.left != nil {
        right.left.parent = n
    }
    right.left = n
    n.parent = right
}
func (t *RBTree) rotateRight(n *rbnode) {
    left := n.left
    t.replace(n, left)
    n.left = left.right
    if left.right != nil {
        left.right.parent = n
    }
    left.right = n
    n.parent = left
}

// Get returns the stored value by given key
func (t *RBTree) Get(key interface{}) interface{} {
    n := t.find(key)
    if n == nil {
        return nil
    }
    return n.v
}

func (t *RBTree) find(key interface{}) *rbnode {
    n := t.root
    for n != nil {
        switch {
        case t.less(key, n.k):
            n = n.left
        case t.less(n.k, key):
            n = n.right
        default:
            return n
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Del deletes the stored value by given key
func (t *RBTree) Del(key interface{}) {
    var child *rbnode

    n := t.find(key)
    if n == nil {
        return
    }

    if n.left != nil && n.right != nil {
        pred := n.left.maximumNode()
        n.k = pred.k
        n.v = pred.v
        n = pred
    }

    if n.left == nil || n.right == nil {
        if n.right == nil {
            child = n.left
        } else {
            child = n.right
        }
        if n.c == black {
            n.c = child.color()
            t.delCase1(n)
        }

        t.replace(n, child)
        if n.parent == nil && child != nil {
            child.c = black
        }
    }
    t.len--
}

func (t *RBTree) delCase1(n *rbnode) {
    if n.parent == nil {
        return
    }

    t.delCase2(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) delCase2(n *rbnode) {
    sibling := n.sibling()
    if sibling.color() == red {
        n.parent.c = red
        sibling.c = black
        if n == n.parent.left {
            t.rotateLeft(n.parent)
        } else {
            t.rotateRight(n.parent)
        }
    }
    t.delCase3(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) delCase3(n *rbnode) {
    sibling := n.sibling()
    if n.parent.color() == black &&
        sibling.color() == black &&
        sibling.left.color() == black &&
        sibling.right.color() == black {
        sibling.c = red
        t.delCase1(n.parent)
        return
    }
    t.delCase4(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) delCase4(n *rbnode) {
    sibling := n.sibling()
    if n.parent.color() == red &&
        sibling.color() == black &&
        sibling.left.color() == black &&
        sibling.right.color() == black {
        sibling.c = red
        n.parent.c = black
        return
    }
    t.delCase5(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) delCase5(n *rbnode) {
    sibling := n.sibling()
    if n == n.parent.left &&
        sibling.color() == black &&
        sibling.left.color() == red &&
        sibling.right.color() == black {
        sibling.c = red
        sibling.left.c = black
        t.rotateRight(sibling)
    } else if n == n.parent.right &&
        sibling.color() == black &&
        sibling.right.color() == red &&
        sibling.left.color() == black {
        sibling.c = red
        sibling.right.c = black
        t.rotateLeft(sibling)
    }
    t.delCase6(n)
}
func (t *RBTree) delCase6(n *rbnode) {
    sibling := n.sibling()
    sibling.c = n.parent.color()
    n.parent.c = black
    if n == n.parent.left && sibling.right.color() == red {
        sibling.right.c = black
        t.rotateLeft(n.parent)
        return
    }
    sibling.left.c = black
    t.rotateRight(n.parent)
}
```

Comment: which complexity did you expect?

Comment: @mangusta time complexity. The benchmark's ns/op is increased by problem size, so it represents time complexity.

Comment: I know that you're talking about time complexity, I mean which time complexity did you expect.

Comment: @mangusta order log n

Comment: so for example in case of "BenchmarkRBTree/size-50000-8" that "ns/op" value implies time spent on a single tree operation performed on the tree of size 50000 ?

Comment: It depends on what your benchmark is calculating, that's why I'm asking my second question. If it calculates total time for insertion of ALL elements into the tree, then naturally the time will not be standing even close to logn

Comment: It looks like you expect to insert N elements into an RB-tree in O(log N) time. Color me pessimistic but my gut feeling is that it ain't gonna happen.

Comment: I am sincerely sorry, this was a bad question, the benchmark was wrongly implemented! Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benchmark was wrongly implemented, a correct version:

```
func BenchmarkRBTree_Put(b *testing.B) {
    count := 0
    grow := 1
    for size := 0; size < 100000; size += 1 * grow {
        if count%10 == 0 {
            count = 1
            grow *= 10
        }
        b.Run(fmt.Sprintf("size-%d", size), func(b *testing.B) {
            // prepare problem size
            tree := NewRBTree(func(a, b interface{}) bool {
                if a.(int) < b.(int) {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            })
            for n := 0; n < size-1; n++ {
                tree.Put(n, n)
            }
            b.ResetTimer()
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                tree.Put(size, size) // only measure the last operation
            }
        })
        count++
    }
}
```

[image]